# Problems in sending SMS to mobile using ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a project on MOBILE ADVERTISING.Im using a following code in which I have to send ads to the user in the form of msg to mobile.This is the code Im using-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using net.webservicex.www;


public partial class msg : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            net.webservicex.www.SendSMS smsIndia = new net.webservicex.www.SendSMS();


            smsIndia.SendSMSToIndia(Txt_Mobile.Text, TxtEmail.Text.Trim(), TxtMessage.Text);


            Label3.Visible = true;
            Label3.Text = "Message Send Succesfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label3.Visible = true;
            Label3.Text = "Error in Sending message" + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

}

There is a error showing for "net" the error is
The type or namespace name 'net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Im desparetly looking for a solution..
Please Help...-(

Comment: Are you using some sort of external SMS library?  Have you included a reference to that library's DLL in your project?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the library containing the net.webservicex.www namespace in the project?

Comment: Where is this error occurring?  Where you import it (using)?  If so, you may need to add a reference to that project in your project file.  Also, with VB.Net anyway once you add the project to your class (Using) you shouldn't have to reference the function by its fully qualified name.

Comment: I don't know how to add reference..

Comment: in Solution Explorer, right click on References, select "Add"

Comment: @Jason I have sucessfuly added the web reference to the namespace net.webservicex.www so the error is gone nw..the label has changed to "msg send sucessfuly" bt the msg is nt received..

Comment: You need to check with whoever is providing the SMS service to see if they have logs or something you can look at to verify your message is getting sent.

Comment: @Jason SORRY I did not understood.Im using web refernce of net.webservicex.www so what is the way of knowing who is providing SMS service

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using webservice only. So I think you are missing that thing.

You can follow the following steps.

Right click on the project -> Add Web Reference -> Write the URL Of the SMS service which you are using.

I think by applying this method I am sure you will solve your problem.